# Escopo entre variáveis - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, escopo-de-variáveis, back-end

Olá!

Estou estudando Javascript e estou com uma dúvida. Venho de um mundo chamado Java e lá existe os modificadores de acesso private, protected, public e até variável sem declaração de modificador; e com isso estou um pouco perdido em javascript.

É possível visualizar a variável do *arquivo1.js* através de uma function, por exemplo, no *arquivo2.js?* Normalmente em java deixamos a variável publica ou usamos getters e setters para tal ação.

Tive essa dúvida pois em um curso online cheguei na parte de escopo e apenas aborda o escopo em relação ao próprio arquivo, mas o rapaz que ensina recomenda ter cuidado com escopos pois uma variável pode estar acessível em qualquer outro lugar do projeto, mas não expõe mais detalhes.

Queria saber como funciona essa questão em javascript, pois meu interesse é aprender a trabalhar com JS no backend com NodeJs.

Algum material que recomendam que eu leia? Ou uma palestra ou vídeo aula que fala sobre?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que isso Explica.
Declare as variáveis fora do return e as funções internas que você desejar esconder, declare conforme código abaixo:

```
var Main = function () {
    var fn = function () { // private
    }

    function fn2 () { // public
    }

    // private attr
    var options = {
        opt1: 'option1',
        opt2: 'option2'
    }

    return {
        options: { // public
         opt1: 'public option 1',
         opt2: 'public option 2'
        },
        init: function () {
         console.log ('Main function loaded...');
        }
    }
}();
```

Veja outro exemplo abaixo:

[image: Encapsulamento js]

Comment: Isto me ajuda bastante. Ainda está difícil de entrar na cabeça 100%, mas eu vou me adaptando. Grato meu caro! Vlw mesmo, ajudou bastante com os exemplos!

Answer (score 3):

Isso que você está falando (*"É possível visualizar a variável do arquivo1.js através de uma function"*) poderia ser possível em diferentes maneiras, mas a API dos navegadores não possibilita diretamente. Seria melhor mesclar seus arquivos utilizando [webpack](https://webpack.github.io), por exemplo (que adiciona uma funcionalidade básica de módulos do Node.JS). Esse utilitário vai criar um fatório para cada arquivo (módulo).

Se o [ECMAScript 4](http://ejohn.org/files/tamarin-and-ecmascript-4.pdf) estivesse presente no JavaScript haveriam modificadores de acesso, e as classes seriam muito mais lindas, até mais do que o ECMAScript 6 (na minha opinião). Por enquanto é possível esconder propriedades sobre uma instância de uma classe (ou similiar...) em uma coleção de referências fracas, ou imitar a solução de @Maurivan (que vai funcionar provavelmente em qualquer navegador).

Comment: É algo bem estranho pra mim, mas estou acostumando aos poucos rsrs Grato meu camarada!